# Unable to take username and password in Twitter account using Selenium

Tags: selenium, twitter, webdriver

I am using below code to login in twitter

```
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("viaxpath");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("viaxpath");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can consider constructing an `xpath` which uniquely identifies the `username` and `password` fields and can be easily traverse-able by Selenium. Here is your own code with some simple tweaks which works at my end:

```
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix field']/input[@name='session[username_or_email]']")).sendKeys("id@domain.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix field']/input[@name='session[password]']")).sendKeys("password");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I've also tried the same code, but twitter is not allowing me to insert username and password in their text fields.

Comment: @Mashhood Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Answer (score 0):

To get a CSS Selector in Chrome:

1. Right-click on the element and select 'Inspect'
2. Right-click on the element in the DOM explorer of DevTools
3. Select "Copy" > "Copy selector"

   1. Alternatively you could get the XPath here too

I was able to input a user name by getting a CSS Selector from Chrome's DevTools and testing it out in the Console.

```
document.querySelector("#page-container > div > div.signin-wrapper > form > fieldset > div:nth-child(2) > input").value = "Timothy"
```

In (Java) Selenium it would look like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#page-container > div > div.signin-wrapper > form > fieldset > div:nth-child(2) > input")).sendKeys("Timothy");
```

One problem you might be experiencing is that you load the page and try to input before its ready. So I recommend doing an [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) between navigating to the page and interacting with the input.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have mentioned is already working. You should be able to enter username and password for twitter account.